# How do I convert a dataframe with one column into a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a single column of numbers.  I want to convert this one column dataframe into a list.  What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Series has a method called [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) for this:

```
df['columnname'].tolist()
```